How can I toggle public network access for azure redis cache using powershell?
How can I toggle public network access for azure redis cache using powershell?
I have tried figuring out a way using Set-AzRedisCache and Get-AzResource through properties and through az resource update, but I can't seem to get to the property or I'm missing something.
EDIT:
In case someone comes here and can't use CLI from the answer for whatever reason, I will briefly mention that I ran into this during my explorations: It is also possible to use a PATCH call like this with Invoke-AzRestMethod (but adapt to correct resource type). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/manage-azure-resources-invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-12.3.0#using-invoke-azrestmethod-with-patch-operations

Hi @Bub, Are you ok Azure CLI command, if yes here is the command to disable Public Network acess az redis update --name "demp-cache" --resource-group "Demo-RG" --set publicNetworkAccess=Disabled

AFAIK, there is no parameter to disable or enable Azure Redis Cache public network access using Azure PowerShell, but you can do this using Azure CLI.
Powershell Command:
$redisCaches = Get-AzRedisCache -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $redisCacheName


Here is the configuration of my Redis Cache before the update.
$redisCache = az redis show --name "demp-cache" --resource-group "Demo-RG"


To enable public network access, you can use the CLI command below
$redisCache = az redis update --name "demp-cache" --resource-group "Demo-RG" --set publicNetworkAccess=Enabled

Output:

After completing the provisioning, the public network access has been changed to the Enabled state.

To toggle public network access for Azure Redis Cache, you can use below code.
$resourceGroupName = "Demo-RG"
$redisCacheName = "demp-cache"

$currentAccess = az redis show --name "$redisCacheName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --query "publicNetworkAccess" -o tsv

if ($currentAccess -eq "Enabled") {
    
    Write-Host "Public network access is now Enabled."
    az redis update --name "$redisCacheName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --set publicNetworkAccess=Disabled
    Write-Host "Public network access is now disabled."
} else {
   
    az redis update --name "$redisCacheName" --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" --set publicNetworkAccess=Enabled
    Write-Host "Public network access is now enabled."
}

Output:

Reference: az redis update
